# How to fix Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil for UIScrollView

Tags: swift, xcode, null

I'm new to Swift, been looking online to find answers about this thread. I did find a lot about the optionals, and I think after that much reading I end understanding the basics of it. Sadly my Vocabulary Knowledge is really limited and I can't seem to find any answers for it. 
My scroll!.delegate = self is returning Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when Built.

I did find a couple of "If" binding examples online, but none of them worked for me. Again, i'm new to this language and even though it shows similarities with others, it seems to behave differently.

```
@IBOutlet weak var scroll:UIScrollView?
@IBOutlet weak var imgv:UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var typeButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scroll!.delegate = self

    }

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imgv
}
```

I think for the most of you, this will be a quick fix. Thanks in advance.

In the end, I just want to have the option of Zooming in a pictures seeing on my View Controller.

Comment: Are you using scroll from Storyboard. If from storyboard it wouldn't be optional. It would be like: @IBOutlet weak var scroll:UIScrollView!
Just change ? to ! and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bhatejaud already said it should be

```
@IBOutlet weak var scroll:UIScrollView!
```

and most importantly: Your scrollView in Storyboard must have a connection to that property in your ViewController class. The missing connection is the reason, why you get this error.

So open your assistant editor in Xcode and **connect** the *ScrollView* in Storyboard with your `scroll` and your *ImageView* in Storyboard with `imgv`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's change `scroll!.delegate = self` to `scroll?.delegate = self`

Dont forget to connect your controls (scrollView, imageView, button) with xib file.